# Xamarin.Android TcpClient not working sometimes

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, tcpclient, .net-7.0

I'm trying to create an application where I have to use WHOIS to get some information I need.

To get the WHOIS information I use this function I found on here and adjusted a little:

```cs
string Whois(string domain, string whoisServer = "whois.iana.org")
{
    string toReturn = "";
    TcpClient tcpClinetWhois = new TcpClient(whoisServer, 43);
    MemoryStream memoryStreamWhois = new MemoryStream();
    Task copying = tcpClinetWhois.GetStream().CopyToAsync(memoryStreamWhois);
    StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(tcpClinetWhois.GetStream());
    streamWriter.WriteLine(domain);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    copying.Wait(3000);
    toReturn = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStreamWhois.ToArray());
    if (toReturn.Contains("refer:"))
    {
        toReturn = Whois(domain, toReturn.Split('\n').Where(W => W.StartsWith("refer:")).Select(R => R.Replace("refer:", "").Trim()).First());
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

When I run it, it works for most TLDs like .com or .org but not for .co.uk or .network and probably others too. I have no idea why it wouldn't work because the right WHOIS server gets selected for the TLD. I am also not getting any errors.

I'm using .Net7.0 and my Android 11 phone for testing.

I've tested this exact same function with the exact same domains on the same network but in a Console Application with no problems at all! Everything works fine except when I try this function in a Xamarin Application.

Comment: `.Wait(3000);` - what is it for?

Comment: For timeout in case the server does not respond, I know it's not the best solution but it does the job

Comment: Why is it wrapped in a task at all?

Comment: Without the timeout, the StreamReader waits for data to be read but none comes, then my application gets stuck there.

Comment: use `await streamReader.ReadLineAsync`

Comment: while (!streamReader.EndOfStream) is wrong.  You will be at the end of stream before you  get any data.  You should add a terminating character at end to the message transmitted and then wait until you receive the end character.  The end character could be a return and then just make the while loop forever using While(true){}

Comment: I cannot use a terminating character because I do not control the WHOIS servers but I edited the function so I have no need for it. The problem is still the same though.